# how to filter repeat data based on repeated id and time interval

Tags: r, repeat, longitudinal

I have longitudinal patient data in R. I would like to subset patients in the patid column based on this condition: three or more occurrences within one year period (one year= any 12 months period)
code to get the same table:

```
structure(list(patid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), observation_date = c("07/07/2016", 
"07/08/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/07/2019", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
"07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "16/06/2015", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
"18/12/2016", "15/01/2017")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Table1:

| patid | observation_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/07/2016 |
| 1 | 07/08/2016 |
| 1 | 07/11/2016 |
| 1 | 07/07/2019 |
| 2 | 07/05/2015 |
| 2 | 02/12/2016 |
| 3 | 07/05/2015 |
| 3 | 07/06/2015 |
| 3 | 16/06/2015 |
| 4 | 07/05/2015 |
| 4 | 02/12/2016 |
| 4 | 18/12/2016 |
| 4 | 15/01/2017 |

The expected table would look like this (a list of patids that meet the criteria; 3 or more observations in 12 months interval)

| patid |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here it's necessary to see the output you expect based on your test data.  It would also be helpful to have your test data in an more usable format, such as the output from `dput()`.  Nevertheless, welcome to SO.

Comment: @abrar_r, I think that this post might be more useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250632/what-is-a-reproducible-example-in-r-and-how-to-do-it?noredirect=1#comment129365802_73250632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above was helpful. I figured I could also do this:

```
#First I only kept patid's with observation dates that are less than 365 days apart
multi_pts <- df %>% 
  arrange(observation_date) %>% 
  group_by(patid) %>% 
  mutate(gap = observation_date - lag(observation_date)) %>%
  filter(gap <365)
#then I  filtered patients that have at least three codes  
count_multi_pts <- 
  multi_pts %>%  
  count(patid) %>% 
  filter(n >= 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels a little long winded to me, so I look forward to see if anyone can make an improvement on it, but I worked out you could do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(patid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                              "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), observation_date = c("07/07/2016", 
                                                                             "07/08/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/07/2019", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                             "07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "16/06/2015", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                             "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                               -13L))

## manipulate the df

df <- df %>%                         
  mutate(
    observation_date = dmy(observation_date),   ## manipulate the dates
    backward = observation_date - 365/2,        ## six months previous
    forward = observation_date + 365/2,         ## six months ahead
    int = backward %--% forward                 ## form interval for checking 
  ) 

## get an empty result table to store results

result_table <- tibble(                         
  patid = NULL,
  observations = NULL
)

## loop that loops through all the observed dates
## filters to get a df with just that patients info
## gets the interval for that observation date and checks if
## any other observation dates are in it
## then sums them in the result$observations
## and adds that to the empty table you created

pats = df %>% distinct(patid)

for(j in 1:length(pats$patid)){
  
  df_pat <- df %>% filter(patid == pats$patid[j])

  for(i in 1:length(df_pat$observation_date)){
  
  df_filt <- df_pat %>% filter(observation_date == df_pat$observation_date[i])
  
  interval_filter = df_filt$int[1]
  
  result <- tibble(
    patid = df_filt$patid[1],
    observations = sum(ifelse(df_pat$observation_date %within% interval_filter,1,0))
  )
  
  result_table <<- rbind(result_table,result)
  
}

}
## this part then give you the desired output

result_table %>%
  filter(observations >= 3) %>% 
  distinct(patid, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: Thank you, this code was helpful but I couldn't get it to work. I think I had something wrong in the loop section. However, I tried this instead and it seems it had worked: 
multi_pts <- df %>% 
  arrange(observation_date) %>% 
  group_by(patid) %>% 
  mutate(gap = observation_date - lag(observation_date)) %>%
  filter(gap <365)
#this codes separates the patients that have at least three codes less than 360 days apart 
count_multi_pts <- 
  multi_pts %>%  
  count(patid) %>% 
  filter(n >= 3)